# Summarize a table where some fields are null values

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got an MySQL table that looks that way:

[image]

Now I want to group the three values on the right, so that there are no null values left. 
So, in total, in this example I would have two rows, each filled with values.

I tried a lot with group statements, but it never goes the way I want.
Any Ideas?

Comment: show what you tried and also the final output you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can aggregate your table according to records sharing the same `t1qrid`, `start`, and `ende` values.  Then use the aggregate function `SUM` to combine the other three columns.  Note that `SUM` will ignore `NULL` values, which seems to be the behavior you want.

```
SELECT t1qrid,
       start,
       ende,
       SUM(Result) AS Result,
       SUM(InclLeft) AS InclLeft,
       SUM(InclRight) AS InclRight
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY t1qrid,
         start,
         ende
```

Comment: Thanky yo so much, that's great! Although I don't really understand, what the SUM does here.

Comment: `SUM` will add together the values of a given column, for a given group of records, while effectively treating `NULL` as 0.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I'll mark your answer as correct, as soon as I can!